# Text sync with running audio

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, synchronization

Does anyone have any idea on how to keep text in sync with audio such that as the audio progresses, the text will autofill or in sync?

What I actual want,is my Audio file is playing and at that time Lyrics of that audio file will be highlighted.

Also if any Application have same functionality then guide me. (sorry for my poor English)

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll be able to automatically sync the text with the audio. If you are on Spotify install the 'TuneWiki' App. This shows song lyrics in time with the music but if you look closely there is a Sync button. Click it and you'll see that users build up the data over time.